# How to load SVG images in Webpack?

Tags: webpack

I'd like to load SVG files using [svgo-loader](https://github.com/rpominov/svgo-loader) in Webpack, but I get the following error:

> ERROR in ./~/css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[name]**[local]**[hash:base64:5]!./~/autoprefixer-loader!./~/less-loader!./demo/src/components/App/components/Header/Header.less
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'logo.svg' in /Users/mishamoroshko/react-autosuggest/demo/src/components/App/components/Header
>    @ ./~/css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[name]**[local]**[hash:base64:5]!./~/autoprefixer-loader!./~/less-loader!./demo/src/components/App/components/Header/Header.less 6:199-218
>
> ERROR in ./demo/src/components/App/components/Header/Header.less
>   Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'logo.svg' in /Users/mishamoroshko/react-autosuggest/demo/src/components/App/components/Header

Here is the relevant code bits:

**Webpack config**

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.less$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!autoprefixer!less'),
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=8192!svgo'
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
"svgo": "^0.6.1",
"svgo-loader": "^1.1.0",
"url-loader": "^0.5.7",
...
```

**Header.less**

```
.logo {
  background-image: url(./logo.svg);
}
```

`logo.svg` and `Header.less` are located in the same directory.

What am I missing here?

---

**To reproduce:**

```
1. git clone git@github.com:moroshko/react-autosuggest.git
2. cd react-autosuggest
3. git checkout a5f1a99
4. npm install
5. npm start
```

Comment: As soon as I remove `modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]`, the error goes away. Perhaps this is a bug at [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader). It may be worth your while to open an issue there to see what the author has to say.

Comment: @bebraw See my answer below

Answer (score 6):

[This `css-loader` issue](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/74) seems related.

As a workaround, changing:

```
background-image: url(./logo.svg);
```

to:

```
background-image: url(../parent-folder/logo.svg);
```

solves the error.