# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'filepath', but the file certainly exists

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a .js file that requires an .svg file:

```
// ...

'.icon': {
   filter: `url(${require('./svg_filters/filters.svg')})`
},

// ...
```

I've checked and double-checked that the file 'svg_filters/filters.svg' exists and is in the right location relative to my .js file.

I've also made sure that my `webpack.config.js` is configured to pack .svg files:

```
// ...

module: {
  loaders: [
    // ...
    {
      test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'file'
    }
  ]
}

// ...
```

But when I try to run webpack, I get this error (edited to scrub my actual project's filenames):

```
ERROR in ./my/script.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg_filters/filters.svg' in '/home/kevin/Programming/project/src/my'
 @ ./src/my/script.js xx:27-63
```

Why am I getting this error? Is there something else I need to set up before webpack can bundle my .svg files?

Comment: What are the literal paths to both the js and the svg?

Comment: @MattiPrice Editing a couple of the directory and file names to keep my project anonymous, the absolute paths are `/home/kevin/Programming/my-project/src/themes/file.js` and `/home/kevin/Programming/my-project/src/themes/svg_filters/filters.svg`.

Comment: You could try copying filters.svg to your root and requiring it from there to see if it's a path issue or if it's something with requiring the .svg itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load SVG images in Webpack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480228/how-to-load-svg-images-in-webpack)

Comment: ^ I found a question that at least partially solved my problem (I'm getting a different error now, at any rate). I'm going to keep on researching, and if it turns out that the specific error I described in this question is fully answered in the question I found, I'll close my question as a duplicate.