# How do I load and link an svg file with webpack 2.2.1?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, svg, webpack-2

I am using webpack version `2.2.1`. I am trying to load a `logo.svg` file into my 
`TopNav` component using an image tag:

```
const logo = require('../client/assets/logo.svg');

const TopNav = () => 
  <div className="top-nav">
    <img src={logo} />
  </div>
```

I am using `file-loader` and `image-webpack-loader` like so:

```
  {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    use: [
      "file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=assets/[hash].[ext]",
      "image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false"
    ]
  }
```

But when I run `npm start`, I get a **You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type** error that reads like this:

```
ERROR in ./client/assets/logo.svg
Module parse failed: /Users/amiterandole/Dropbox/projects/techchatfest/client/assets/logo.svg Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 841.9 595.3">
|     <g fill="#61DAFB">
|         <path d="M666.3 296.5c0-32.5-40.7-63.3-103.1-82.4 14.4-63.6 8-114.2-20.2-130.4-6.5-3.8-14.1-5.6-22.4-5.6v22.3c4.6 0 8.3.9 11.4 2.6 13.6 7.8 19.5 37.5 14.9 75.7-1.1 9.4-2.9 19.3-5.1 29.4-19.6-4.8-41-8.5-63.5-10.9-13.5-18.5-27.5-35.3-41.6-50 32.6-30.3 63.2-46.9 84-46.9V78c-27.5 0-63.5 19.6-99.9 53.6-36.4-33.8-72.4-53.2-99.9-53.2v22.3c20.7 0 51.4 16.5 84 46.6-14 14.7-28 31.4-41.3 49.9-22.6 2.4-44 6.1-63.6 11-2.3-10-4-19.7-5.2-29-4.7-38.2 1.1-67.9 14.6-75.8 3-1.8 6.9-2.6 11.5-2.6V78.5c-8.4 0-16 1.8-22.6 5.6-28.1 16.2-34.4 66.7-19.9 130.1-62.2 19.2-102.7 49.9-102.7 82.3 0 32.5 40.7 63.3 103.1 82.4-14.4 63.6-8 114.2 20.2 130.4 6.5 3.8 14.1 5.6 22.5 5.6 27.5 0 63.5-19.6 99.9-53.6 36.4 33.8 72.4 53.2 99.9 53.2 8.4 0 16-1.8 22.6-5.6 28.1-16.2 34.4-66.7 19.9-130.1 62-19.1 102.5-49.9 102.5-82.3zm-130.2-66.7c-3.7 12.9-8.3 26.2-13.5 39.5-4.1-8-8.4-16-13.1-24-4.6-8-9.5-15.8-14.4-23.4 14.2 2.1 27.9 4.7 41 7.9zm-45.8 106.5c-7.8 13.5-15.8 26.3-24.1 38.2-14.9 1.3-30 2-45.2 2-15.1 0-30.2-.7-45-1.9-8.3-11.9-16.4-24.6-24.2-38-7.6-13.1-14.5-26.4-20.8-39.8 6.2-13.4 13.2-26.8 20.7-39.9 7.8-13.5 15.8-26.3 24.1-38.2 14.9-1.3 30-2 45.2-2 15.1 0 30.2.7 45 1.9 8.3 11.9 16.4 24.6 24.2 38 7.6 13.1 14.5 26.4 20.8 39.8-6.3 13.4-13.2 26.8-20.7 39.9zm32.3-13c5.4 13.4 10 26.8 13.8 39.8-13.1 3.2-26.9 5.9-41.2 8 4.9-7.7 9.8-15.6 14.4-23.7 4.6-8 8.9-16.1 13-24.1zM421.2 430c-9.3-9.6-18.6-20.3-27.8-32 9 .4 18.2.7 27.5.7 9.4 0 18.7-.2 27.8-.7-9 11.7-18.3 22.4-27.5 32zm-74.4-58.9c-14.2-2.1-27.9-4.7-41-7.9 3.7-12.9 8.3-26.2 13.5-39.5 4.1 8 8.4 16 13.1 24 4.7 8 9.5 15.8 14.4 23.4zM420.7 163c9.3 9.6 18.6 20.3 27.8 32-9-.4-18.2-.7-27.5-.7-9.4 0-18.7.2-27.8.7 9-11.7 18.3-22.4 27.5-32zm-74 58.9c-4.9 7.7-9.8 15.6-14.4 23.7-4.6 8-8.9 16-13 24-5.4-13.4-10-26.8-13.8-39.8 13.1-3.1 26.9-5.8 41.2-7.9zm-90.5 125.2c-35.4-15.1-58.3-34.9-58.3-50.6 0-15.7 22.9-35.6 58.3-50.6 8.6-3.7 18-7 27.7-10.1 5.7 19.6 13.2 40 22.5 60.9-9.2 20.8-16.6 41.1-22.2 60.6-9.9-3.1-19.3-6.5-28-10.2zM310 490c-13.6-7.8-19.5-37.5-14.9-75.7 1.1-9.4 2.9-19.3 5.1-29.4 19.6 4.8 41 8.5 63.5 10.9 13.5 18.5 27.5 35.3 41.6 50-32.6 30.3-63.2 46.9-84 46.9-4.5-.1-8.3-1-11.3-2.7zm237.2-76.2c4.7 38.2-1.1 67.9-14.6 75.8-3 1.8-6.9 2.6-11.5 2.6-20.7 0-51.4-16.5-84-46.6 14-14.7 28-31.4 41.3-49.9 22.6-2.4 44-6.1 63.6-11 2.3 10.1 4.1 19.8 5.2 29.1zm38.5-66.7c-8.6 3.7-18 7-27.7 10.1-5.7-19.6-13.2-40-22.5-60.9 9.2-20.8 16.6-41.1 22.2-60.6 9.9 3.1 19.3 6.5 28.1 10.2 35.4 15.1 58.3 34.9 58.3 50.6-.1 15.7-23 35.6-58.4 50.6zM320.8 78.4z"/>
 @ ./common/TopNav.js 2:11-47
 @ ./common/App.js
 @ ./server/server.js
 @ ./server/index.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/poll?1000 ./server/index
```

I have also tried using svgo, react-svg etc. But none of them work. What is the right way to do this?

Tha answer given here is outdated: [How to load SVG images in Webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480228/how-to-load-svg-images-in-webpack)

Here is my full `webpack.client.config.js` file for reference:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const precss = require("precss");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const ant = require('postcss-ant')

module.exports = {
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  entry: [
    "react-hot-loader/patch",
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3001",
    "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
    "./client/index",
  ],
  target: "web",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: "babel-loader",
        include: [
          path.join(__dirname, "client"),
          path.join(__dirname, "common"),
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss|css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          "file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=assets/[hash].[ext]",
          "image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false"
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: [ "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: [ "file-loader" ]
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": { BUILD_TARGET: JSON.stringify("client") },
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      test: /\.scss|css$/,
      debug: true,
      options: {
          postcss: function() {
              return [ ant, precss, autoprefixer ];
          },
          context: path.join(__dirname, "client"),
          output: { path: path.join(__dirname, ".build") }
      }
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3001,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, ".build"),
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3001/",
    filename: "client.js",
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This loader works for me.

```
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
    loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
}
```

Comment: Have you removed svg from (ttf|eot|svg) and (jpe?g|png|gif|svg) loaders before adding this one?

Comment: yes I have removed svg from that test above. I am using `"url-loader": "^0.5.8"`